# Como usar beforeSave no CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp

Estou tentando pegar o array de imagem para tratar

No CakePHP 2, eu fazia assim:

```
    public function beforeSave($options = array())
    {
    if(!empty($this->data['User']['picture']['name'])...
```

Alguém poderia explicar a nova sintaxe do Cake 3:

```
beforeSave
Cake\ORM\Table::beforeSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, ArrayObject $options)
```

?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Isso deve ajudar o seu problema na implementação

```
// Uses da class - além dos demais necessários
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

// Seu método
public function beforeSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, \ArrayObject $options)
{
    if (isset($entity->picture) && !empty($entity->picture)) {
        $entity->set('picture', trim($entity->picture));
    }
}
```